# Xamarin.Mac installer not working

Tags: xamarin, provisioning-profile, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin.Mac solution that runs correctly in Debug or Release build from within Xamarin Studio, but I am struggling to create a working installer for it.

I want to use direct distribution (outside the App Store), so this is the procedure I used to create the installer:

Within the Apple developer portal:

- Created "Developer ID" application and installer certificates
- Created an App ID for the app
- Created a provisioning profile that references the App ID and the
  application certificate
- Downloaded the 2 certificates and the provision profile

On the development Mac:

- Double-clicked the 2 certificates and verified that they were
  installed in Keychain Access
- Double-clicked the provisioning profile and verified that it was
  installed in Profiles

Within Xcode:

- Opened Preferences > Accounts and downloaded the provisioning profile
- Restarted Xcode to propagate the downloads to Xamarin Studio

Within Xamarin Studio:

- Configured the Bundle ID in `info.plist` (to match the App ID)
- Selected the Release build signing identity, as created above
- Selected the Release build provisioning profile, as created above
- Selected the Release build installer identity, as created above
- Rebuilt the solution in Release build configuration

After the build is complete, the `bin/Release` folder contains everything I would expect, including the `.pkg` and `.app` files.

If I double-click the `.pkg` file, it appears to correctly execute the installation sequence, but the installed app is not listed in Applications or Launchpad. Moreover, if I run the `.app` file from its `bin/Release` folder, it executes correctly, but if I manually move it to the Applications folder, it crashes on startup.

Within Utilities > System Information > Software > Applications, I can see that the app was installed and that its source is an "Identified Developer", so this seems to confirm that the signing worked correctly.

I'm puzzled why, if it was correctly installed, I am unable to run it.

Sorry, I am quite new to both Mac and Xamarin.Mac, so I am not completely sure what I should expect to see here, but I assume it's more than I am currently seeing.

Any clues please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely if you are able to run an application locally but not able to via an installed package, you are running into code signing issues.

As noted [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/application_fundamentals/troubleshooting/#What_To_Do_When_Your_App_Crashes_With_No_Output) you could try running your application from the command line:

> Run your application from the command line and look at the output (in
>   the Terminal app) by using:  MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp (where
>   MyApp is the name of your application)

and see if you are getting a code signing specific error on launch.

If so, then possibly your machine may not be on the provisioning profile/certificate selected.

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful. Using this technique, I can see that the reason the app crashes on startup, when run from the Applications folder, is because it cannot find its localized resource DLLs (which I will need to investigate as a separate problem). However, I am still puzzled why the package installer doesn't attempt to install the .app into the Applications folder.

Comment: There is a strange installer bug where if you run the installer in place next to the app bundle it doesn't install in the /Application folder.  Try moving the pkg to another location and then doing a clean in XS. Maybe that will help. It seems to be a packagebuild bug fwict.

Comment: Thanks again @Chris. I tried your latest suggestion and, unfortunately it didn't make any difference. Is there somewhere I can download a sample Xamarin.Mac project which includes a working example of packaging? Alternatively (since I guess you are a Xamarin insider) do you know how I can get paid support on this issue? Thanks again.

Comment: Since this is starting to sound like support more than a simple question, may I suggest you making a post on https://forums.xamarin.com/categories/mac instead of the comment section on StackOverflow?

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Yes, I'll do that (and I have accepted your answer, as it is effectively moving me closer to a solution).

Comment: @TimCoulter : Can you please help on this exact issue ? I'm also struggling to make build and if build done then installer doesn't work.

Comment: @SagarPanwala : sorry, but this issue arose a very long time ago and my memory isn't that good. I confirm that I did eventually solve the problem and that the app is now working correctly, but I honestly can't remember what the fix was. If I tried to guide you, I would be guessing and would probably do more harm than good. Good luck, anyway.